# Python: Change a word like ”abcdefg” by using every other letter ”aceg” and then adding the rest in order ”bdf.”

Tags: python

I have this assignment:

> You want to make a code to hide your message, but not make it too hard for the receiver to decode. Each code will be all lowercase letters (it will ignore the last character in the last word to leave the punctuation the same). You will change a word like "abcdefg" by using every other letter "aceg" and then adding the rest in order "bdf." So "abcdefg" becomes "acegbdf." Note, a 1 or 2-letter word will remain unchanged. You must also capitalize the first letter of each sentence.
>
> **Input:** A sentence will have all lowercase characters.
>
> **Sample Input:**
>
> ```
> sentence = ["this", "is", "a", "test", "of", "the", "emergency", "broadcast", "system"]
> ```
>
> **Output:** `"Tihs is a tset of teh eegnymrec bodatracs sseytm."`

This is what I have so far. I have no clue how to work on it even I studied the Python book, sorry for the little input here!

```
for word in sentence:
    print word[::3],
    print word[::1]
```

Comment: "string slicing" is the keyword you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new_sentence = ''
for word in sentence:
    new_sentence += word[::2] + word[1::2] + ' '
print(new_sentence.strip().capitalize())
```

Output:

```
Tihs is a tset of teh eegnymrec bodatracs sseytm
```

Comment: the strip() method eliminates it.

Comment: Thank you very much! It helps a lot!